# How to install SQLite version 3.35.0 to a C# .Net Form Application Project

Tags: c#, sqlite, installation, nuget

I am working on a C# .Net Framework project and I want to install sqlite version 3.35.0. But when I download System.Data.Sqlite package from visual studio Nuget Package and write the below code:

```
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = testDatabase");
        string version = con.ServerVersion;
```

Output value of the version is: 3.32.1

I looked into the official SQlite website and see that for .Net, they didn't release this 3.35.0 version of it. Only 3.32.1 version available in this website: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

I need 3.35.0 version of Sqlite because they added the DROP COLUMN function in this version or higher.

So is there any way that I can install 3.35.x version of Sqlite .dll file to my project ?

Thanks for helping.